# Which IP address goes in proxy_pass when configuring NGINX

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

Which IP address goes in the location proxy_pass in the NGINX configuration file `nginx.conf`?  Is it public IP address of the server?

```
http {
  ...
  location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://<which ip address goes in here?>:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't have to be public but your nginx has to be able to resolve it. It can be a private network IP address or `127.0.0.1` if your back-end runs on the same machine.